# Java chain classes

Tags: java, methods

I build a main class runs 5 classes, and make them able to pass string to each other. I just post main class + class 1 and 4.

Main class:

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args){

    class4 c4 = new class4(c1);

    class3 c3 = new class3(c4);

    class2 c2 = new class2(c3);
    c2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    c2.setSize(200,100);
    c2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    c2.setVisible(true);

    class1 c1 = new class1(c2);
    c1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    c1.setSize(200,100);
    c1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    c1.setVisible(true);


}
```

}

Class 1:

```
public class class1 extends JFrame{
private JButton jb;

private class2 c2;
public class1(class2 c2){
    this();
    this.c2 = c2;
    }


public class1(){
    super("");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    jb = new JButton("click click");
    add(jb);

    jb.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    sayHi("Hi buddy");
                }});
}
public void sayHi(String x){
    c2.recieveHi(x);
}

public void recieveHi(String x){
    System.out.println(x);
}

}
```

Class 5:

```
public class class4 {

private class1 c1;
public class4(class1 c1){
    //this();
    this.c1 = c1;
}
public void recieveHi(String x){
    System.out.println(x);
    killMessenger();
}
public void killMessenger(){
    String s = "back to class 1";
    c1.recieveHi(s);
}

}
```

Class 1 pass String to class2, which pass String to class 3 etc.. When class4 recieve String, i need to pass a String to class1.. As you can see in my main class, i need to bind them e.g

```
class 1 c1 = new class1(c2);
```

Doing it with `class4 c4 = new class4(c1)` doesn't work, because class1 isn't made yet. There will always be an lose end to it, so there might be a method to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a `setter` method, so you don't pass `c1` in the constructor but after the `class1` instance is created. In your `class4` class

```
public void setClass1Object(class1 pC1) {
    this.c1 = pC1;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but didnt worked.. I guess its because i dont imported the method correctly, could you please help?? error is NullPointerException

Comment: Do you get any error? Or it just don't work as expected. Please provide more information.

Comment: The error is: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I think you have to check `if (c1 != null) { ... }` in the `killMessenger()` method. A recommendation, give more descriptive names to your classes and Java naming conventions.

Comment: that didnt worked either. Just broke the code, and didnt passed a value to class1.. made a new thread with all the classes attacthed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221211/need-help-to-link-classes