# Need help to link classes

Tags: java, class, methods

As the title suggests, I need help to link classes. I got one main class, and 4 classes which are going to pass to each other!

My code:

**Mainclass:** run all the 4 classes

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        class4 c4 = new class4();
        class3 c3 = new class3(c4);
        class2 c2 = new class2(c3);

        c2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        c2.setSize(200,100);
        c2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        c2.setVisible(true);

        class1 c1 = new class1(c2);
        c1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        c1.setSize(200,100);
        c1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        c1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**class1:** pass a String to a method in class2.

```
public class class1 extends JFrame{
    private JButton jb;

    private class4 c4;
    private class2 c2;

    public class1(class2 c2){
        this();
        this.c2 = c2;
    }

    public class1(){
        super("");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        jb = new JButton("click click");
        add(jb);

        jb.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        sayHi("Hi buddy");
                    }});
    }

    public void sayHi(String x){
        c2.recieveHi(x);
    }

    public void recieveHi(String x){
        System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

**class2:** Output String from class1, and pass a String to class3

```
public class class2 extends JFrame{
    private JTextField jt;

    private class3 c3;

    public class2(class3 c3){
        this();
        this.c3 = c3;
    }

    public class2(){
        super("Yeds");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        jt = new JTextField(12);
        add(jt);
        //recieveHi("hey");
    }

    public void recieveHi(String x){
        String j = x;
        jt.setText(j);
        sayHi();
    }

    public void sayHi(){
        c3.recieveHi("Hey class3");
    }
}
```

**class3:** Output String from class2, and pass a String to class4

```
public class class3 {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    private class4 c4;
    public class3(class4 c4){
        //this();
        this.c4 = c4;
        }

    public void recieveHi(String x){
        System.out.println(x);
        sayHi();

        //sayHi();
    }
    public void sayHi(){
        System.out.println();
        c4.recieveHi("Hey class4");
    }
}
```

**class4:** Output String from class3, and are supposed to send a String back to class1. But I can't make it work.

A problem is that I can't link them in mainclass, because this: `class4 c4 = new class4(c1);` doesn't work, `c1` isn't simply made when class4 needs it, so that's not an option.

```
    public class class4 {
    private class1 c1;

    //this are supposed to work, but doesnt...
    public void setClass1Object(class1 pC1) {
        this.c1 = pC1;
    }

    public void recieveHi(String x){
        System.out.println(x);
        killMessenger();
        setClass1Object(c1);
    }

    public void killMessenger(){
        String s = "back to class 1";
        c1.recieveHi(s);
    }
}
```

To simple that, all I need is to being able to send a String back to class1. I need it for a bigger project, and all the classes have to get opened from the mainclass.

Comment: Classes begin with a capital letter.
A class should represent something, it make no sense to call things "classX".

Comment: This is just a code i made to reproduce the problem i got in my real project. Thought it would be easier just to call them 1,2,3 etc. :-)

Comment: @KevinBowersox I tried create an constructor before, but the problem is, that in the main class, class4 are made before class1, and it cant add so class4 c4 = new class4(c1); will not work unless i put class1 c1 = new class1(); at the top of the main class..

Comment: @KevinBowersox But if i put class1 c1 = new class1(c2) at the top of my main class, c2 are created later then c1, and therefor class1 wont work..

Comment: You should use the same work flow as you used to passing message. like from c1 to c2 and then c2 to c3 and then c3 to c4. If you want to give some that from c4 to c1 then you first request it from c2 and then c2 request it from c3 and then c3 request it from c4.

Comment: If you want to directly link the c1 and c4 then why you first used the approach of chaining in sending message.?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220273/java-chain-classes can someone report it? I have no flags lefr

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220273/java-chain-classes please report it, cause I have no flags left

Answer (score 0):

I think if you should first initialize all the classes and afterwards to set them visible.
If you do like this probably it will work:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
  class4 c4 = new class4();
  class3 c3 = new class3(c4);
  class2 c2 = new class2(c3);
  class1 c1 = new class1(c2);
  c4.setClass1Object(c1);
  // here make all the setters like setSize, setVisible etc
}
```